# Gradle junit-tests are failing for the same exact code that works in main with same dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, jackson, yaml, junit4

I am using **gradle-2.8** version due to organisation restrictions.

I am trying to read YAML file (OpenAPI - swagger specification) using the following code :

```
new OpenAPIParser().readLocation(urlString, null, parseOptions).getOpenAPI();
```

which is present in both the `main` and `test` sourceSets as it is.

I have defined 2 configurations

- `swagConfig` (for compile time dependencies)
- `swagRuntime` (for runtime dependencies)

where `swagRuntime` consists of the following dependencies :

```
'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.12.1'
'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1'
'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.1'
'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.1'
```

and the build.gradle includes the following :

```
configurations {
    compile.extendsFrom swagConfig
    runtime.extendsFrom swagRuntime
    runtime {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.12.1'
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1'
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.1'
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.1'
        }
    }
    testRuntime {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.12.1'
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1'
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.1'
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.1'
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I execute my `main` source-Set code, it works perfectly fine but when I run my `test` sourceSet based JUnit Test, I am running into failure :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.events.ScalarEvent.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/events/ImplicitTuple;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/error/Mark;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/error/Mark;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/DumperOptions$ScalarStyle;)V
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator._scalarEvent(YAMLGenerator.java:908)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator._writeScalar(YAMLGenerator.java:879)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator.writeNull(YAMLGenerator.java:787)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer.serialize(NullSerializer.java:30)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serializeNull(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:495)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:303)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._writeValueAndClose(ObjectWriter.java:1215)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:1085)
    at io.swagger.v3.core.util.Yaml.pretty(Yaml.java:23)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.converter.SwaggerConverter.readResult(SwaggerConverter.java:113)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.converter.SwaggerConverter.readLocation(SwaggerConverter.java:91)
    at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation(OpenAPIParser.java:16)
```

**Debugging**

After further debugging the stacktrace, my guess is that the `jackson-dataformat-yaml` artifact being used is somehow not `2.12.1` but `2.9` or less because in `2.9` the constructor of `org.yaml.snakeyaml.events.ScalarEvent.<init>` with that signature is not found (I could be wrong as well).

I have tried printing the

- `classpath`
- the `testRuntime` configuration and it's resolved artifacts.

and I see that the `2.12.1` version itself for `jackson-dataformat-yaml` is being picked up everywhere. But still I am not clear why the build (with junit) fails as explained above.

Could anyone help in debugging this further or any insight into why the `test` sourceSet for JUnits is not resolving the artifacts correctly.

Appreciate all inputs.
Thanks.